# The correct usage of very vs a very

Tags: usage, indefinite-article

I would appreciate if you explain why "a" has been added before "very"in the following sentence:

> I hope you have a very nice evening.

Is this sentence still correct without "a" before very?

> I hope you have very nice evening.

Answer (score 5):

The word "very" is irrelevant. "nice evening" takes a determiner, in this case "a". Putting "very" in front of it doesn't change that; it still needs the "a".

Comment: It doesn't even depend on the word "nice". "Evening" is a countable noun, so it does need the article.

Comment: @MrLister The one caveat would be that without "nice", it would be "an" instead of "a", since it's next to a word that starts with a vowel.

Comment: And of course, you can say "good evening" without "a". Oh well.